# Assessing Formality via the Root of the Word

Tags: word-choice, formality

Firstly, I'd point out that as this is a slightly open-ended question I'm not certain how well it fits in with the guideline. I'm hoping that the fact there's a way to define an answer means that it is not necessarily wrong.

So, the question came to me after reading this article here: [English is not normal](https://aeon.co/essays/why-is-english-so-weirdly-different-from-other-languages). What stood out for me was how the author described that a method of judging the formality of what is being said is through the origin of the word used -- the author also brought two distinct examples ('help'/'aid'/'assist' and 'kingly'/'royal'/'regal') where the Old English > English word is the least formal of the possible options, the French word is the middle ground and the Latin derivation is the most formal.

What other pairs of this kind exist, and is this the best way of determining formality? Does this mean that the best way to make a statement less/more formal is replacing words with their synonyms based on the origin of the synonym (example: "Kingly help was given"/"Royal aid was presented"/"Regal assistance was provided")?

Comment: The question is interesting. The article you mention is trash, though. Comparative linguistics is a fascinating discipline, but assertions made by monolingual folks always sound a bit comical. You know, as the poet said, "She liked the English and the Hebrew tongue/And said there was analogy between them/She proved it somehow out of sacred song/But I must leave the proofs to those who've seen them."

Comment: You asked for other pairs, but you didn't list pairs; you listed triplets.  Setting aside the inappropriate solicitation that people chime in with lists of words and their opinions about their registers, had you read the article, it answers the only legitimate question you make quite clearly and explicitly.  It says that you cannot measure the formal or informal register of a word merely based on word origin.  It's not that cut and dry.  Setting that aside, the article is little more than a litany of unsubstantiated, nonsensical malarkey. It's an interesting but complete conjecture.

Comment: The best way of judging the formality of different words with similar meanings is to *look at contexts where they're used* (through Google Books, for example). The simplistic *Latin:formal, French:normal, Anglo-Saxon:only for peasants* is far too crude to be of much help in the real world. You'd probably get just as reliable results if you based your judgement soley on the number of letters in each word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'd give you +1000 for "Anglo-Saxon: only for peasants" if I could. And another thousand for "if you based your judgment solely on the number of letters in each word." Great stuff, dude!

Comment: @Ricky: I think it's a bit ott to say that article is "trashy". It seems pretty obvious to me the guy knows his onions (or whatever the Latin equivalent of that is! :) Anyway, I only glanced through it, but I *like* it - mainly because I see he mentions the *cow:beef, pig:pork* split, which I always think is an excellent example of how those bastard Norman overlords distorted our language by making us use *their* words for what *they* ate, where *we* had the mundane task of feeding, slaughtering, and cooking the animals for them (and doubtless gnawing the bones clean after they'd finished).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You do have a point. However, my ... uh ... _feeling_ ... grrr ... I hate that word ... anyway, uh ... It's misleading precisely because he gets a few things right. Someone just might assume that the nonsense he piles on about German and Dutch, Russian and Hebrew, the Celts, etc, is actually true. One of Dumas' characters claims that "English is simply French poorly pronounced," but that's a joke; this guy is for real.

Comment: @Ricky: Checking the *provenance* of the article, it seems that John McWhorter has solid credentials. But he's writing a "flip" piece there (for a magazine?) so you've got to expect a certain amount of simplification. It's not presenting itself as a formal study aid (but apparently McWhorter has written stuff more in that vein, and I've no reason to suppose it would be any more "trashy" than books by, for example, Steven Pinker).

Comment: That's actually a pretty good piece.  It's obviously written in a style intended to ruffle the feathers of various categories of pedants and purists, but that helps keep it amusing.  I didn't read anything in there that I could identify as blatantly false, but I'm sure that there are some details some people will violently disagree with.  What fun!!

Comment: @FumbleFingers : I'm sorry to disappoint but pig*/*pork and cow*/*beef isn't specific to English or the result of the Normans. In Latin and Latin-based languages it's the same. Meats are different than their animals. In Spanish, a pig is a puerco and pork is cerdo, chicken is gallina and chicken poultry is pollo, etc. The same thing happens in Portuguese. I imagine it's that way in French and Italian, too. So, while the Normans may have been rat bastards, we can't pin this on them.  Maybe the words, but not the convention.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: Come to think of it, it's pretty common in all European languages, Germanic, Romance, and Slavic. I have a couple of friends in the Finno-Ugric group, I'll ask them to confirm. I'd be curious to know what the Mandarin speakers make of this.

Comment: @Benjamin: My school may have been a bit more hard-line that most on such matters, but I was always taught that it's okay to pin *anything and everything* on the Normans. I'm sure I remember our RE teacher explaining how it was the rat-fink Normans who gave the serpent the idea of talking Eve into tricking Adam into eating that apple. (Okay, maybe he didn't call them ***rat-fink** Normans*, but you get the general idea! :)

Comment: ...apropos which, I think I actually got the *cow:beef / pig:pork* "insight" from Steven Pinker many years ago. *And* I think I may have been shot down in flames for bringing it up here on ELU somewhat less years ago. But I'm not one to let facts stand in the way of a good argument (esp if the target of the argument is in any way Gallic! :)

Comment: I have certainly heard the cow/beef thing several times, and find that less suspect than some of the other things in the piece.

Comment: FWIW, (at least modern) French does *not* use different words for the animal and the meat, in general. And can someone please demonstrate that English *did* have different words (though not French ones) for the two before the Norman conquest? If that is the rule for "*all European languages*", are French and English (< 1066) exceptions to this rule?

Comment: @Ricky: The Finno-Ugric that I am familiar with does not carry that distinction, with the meats being the same words (though compound) as the animals.

Comment: With regards to the rest, there's a lot of attention in the comments devoted to a bit of the article that I didn't particularly mention myself. I feel that @FumbleFingers has provided the best overall response to the question I sought -- however, what would be your suggestion in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern works pretty well for the often mentioned animal/food pairs.  informal animal:sheep

The list of pairs or triples is endless. Just a handful:

- land/country/nation
- friendly/amiable
- drink/beverage
- wound/injury
- room/chambre
- woods/forest
- child/infant/juvenile

This is good rule of thumb, but isn't absolutely perfect. There's hips (OE) and haunches (hips/legs, OFr) and ham (leg (of ham) OFr), where hips is the most formal of all of them. Ward (OE)/guard (OF), corner/angle, neck/collar, harvest/autumn all seem of the same formality

Another difference, in addition to formality, is the Anglo-Saxon is usually more concrete, the Romance more abstract.

The pattern also works well for legal or medical terms: theft/larceny,  hand:manual, knee:genuflect, head:capital (and then Greek neologisms are created for even more synonyms).

But these technical medical terms are more likely to be technical neologisms well after 1066, by scientifically minded individuals rather than social language sharing via an invasion.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of making statements less formal, you really have to take it case by case, but the Old-English word would be less formal in many cases (e.g., Holy Ghost versus Holy Spirit). In the case of *kingly*/*royal*/*regal*, the word *royal* has become far more common than *kingly*, so switching from the former to the latter would not make the sentence sound less formal.
Another example is *autumn*(F) versus fall(OE). In that case, autumn is perhaps slightly more formal, but it is common enough in everyday usage that replacing it would have only a minor effect. 
In some cases, there are slight differences in how the French and OE versions of a word are used. You would not say, "Let's have cow for dinner!" That would sound ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

It's a great assertion, but shall we not firstly separate English dialects at the outset? Surely, North American English, British English, Aussie English, etc. assign different levels of formality to these very same words. "Kingly", to me, appears very archaic and therefore formal. I find that by ignoring cultural and geographical dimensions of the English language, you are really arriving at an incorrect conclusion (at least practically).

Comment: I think you have pointed out a very valid aspect of this question; I guess as living in Britain it is too natural to think of the 'correct' British (and, hence, the one being referred to) as the GB version. I wonder if one was to do as you have said and see what people thought, how would it vary between the various places. But, anecdotally, you say that "kingly" is the most formal due to its archaic root?