# Retrospect(ive) vs. Hindsight?

Tags: word-usage

I use both words, but only now does it occur to me, what's the actual.difference?

Specifically this kind of usage:

- "in restrospect" (or "retrospectively") "we should have thought of that"
  vs
  "in hindsight we should have thought of that"

Comment: I would say the major differences are that **hindsight** is more colloquial and used more in idioms/sayings; "Hindsight is 2020." Also "hindsight" can't be made into an adjective or adverb . "Retrospective" on the other hand sounds kind of technical.

Comment: What has your research shown?

Answer (score 1):

*Retrospect* refers to any instance of looking back at the past. *Hindsight* usually implies a realisation that you would have done something different, or seen a situation in another light, if you had known what you know today.

Comment: What about "in restrospect" (or "retrospectively") "we should have thought of that", vs "in hindsight...,." ?

Comment: I didn't say you _couldn't_ use 'in retrospect' in that sense, just that 'with hindsight' has that _particular_ meaning.

Comment: Yes - that said however, its that sense I'm trying to understand if there is a difference? Edited question to clarify - and thank you so far!

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is connotation.

- **Retrospect** (first used in 17th century according to the OED) comes from the Latin *retro-* (back) and *-spectus* (from the verb *specio*, *specere* - to look or watch).
- **Hindsight** (first used in 19th century according to the OED) comes from Old English / Germanic *hind* (back, behind) and *sight* (see, look).

In terms of connotation, words with Latin origins in English tend to be heard as more technical or professional, whereas words from Old English or Germanic origins tend to be heard as more colloquial or to-the-point. (See this EL&U exchange, "[Assessing Formality via the Root of the Word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/300478/assessing-formality-via-the-root-of-the-word/393538)," for more pairs or triads of words that work similarly).

So these words preceded by "in" mean similar things and are often used interchangeably, but *retrospect* carries a whiff of the erudite while *hindsight* sounds a touch more brisk. That said, the connotations are pretty weak. For example:

> [In **retrospect**, it was the beginning of the end of Morris's tenure as head coach.](https://www.buccaneers.com/news/potential-buccaneer-firsts-in-2019-london-win)
>
> [In **hindsight**, Perez regrets choosing McLaren over Ferrari](https://f1i.com/news/337650-in-hindsight-perez-regrets-choosing-mclaren-over-ferrari.html)